# Swig convert vector<std::string> to native PHP array

Tags: php, c++, c++11, swig

I begin to work with `swig` and `php`, and I would like to return a `std::vector<std::string>` to my `php` code.I have try this (all compilation work).

my swig file :

```
%module example
%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>

%{
    extern std::vector<std::string> testSwig(const char *path);
%}

//try here to convert vector to native php array
%typemap(out) const std::vector<std::string> & {
    array_init($result);
    Array::const_iterator i = $1->begin();
    Array::const_iterator e = $1->end();
    for(; i != e; ++i ) {
        zval * data;
        MAKE_STD_ZVAL(data);
        ZVAL_STRINGL(data, (char*)i->c_str(), i->size(), 1);
        zend_hash_next_index_insert( HASH_OF($result), &data, sizeof(zval *), NULL );
    }
}

extern std::vector<std::string> testSwig(const char *path);
```

my cpp file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> testSwig(const char *path)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("test 1");
    v.push_back("test 2");
    v.push_back("try vector");

    return v;
}
```

And finaly my php file to try this :

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    echo print_r(testSwig('try arg'));
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

My problem is that my conversion `std::vector` to `php` array doesn't work; when I made my `print_r` I have this result : `resource(1) of type (_p_std__vectorT_std__string_t)`

Comment: What version of PHP are you targeting?

Comment: PHP version 5.6 @Flexo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was pretty close to working, but it wasn't getting applied correctly because of a type-mismatch. Your out typemap was written as `const std::vector<std::string> &`, whereas the test function you used simply returned `std::vector<std::string>`, i.e. not const and by value, not by reference.

With that fixed it then becomes apparent that there is no type defined called `Array` in your code, and that `$1` is actually an instance of `std::vector<std::string>`, not a pointer to on. I used `$1_ltype` to make SWIG generate the correct fully qualified type for the input to the typemap. So to make your code work we need to modify it thus:

```
%module test

%{
#include <string>
#include <vector>
%}

%typemap(out) std::vector<std::string> {
    array_init($result);
    $1_type::const_iterator i = $1.begin();
    $1_type::const_iterator e = $1.end();
    for(; i != e; ++i ) {
        zval * data;
        MAKE_STD_ZVAL(data);
        ZVAL_STRINGL(data, (char*)i->c_str(), i->size(), 1);
        zend_hash_next_index_insert( HASH_OF($result), &data, sizeof(zval *), NULL );
    }
}

%inline %{
std::vector<std::string> testSwig(const char *path)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("test 1");
    v.push_back("test 2");
    v.push_back("try vector");

    return v;
}
%}
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5 that was sufficient to let the following test case work as you hoped:

```
<?php
include('test.php');
print_r(test::testSwig('hello'));
?>
```

Which I compiled and ran as:

```
swig -php -c++ test.i
g++ test_wrap.cpp $(php-config --includes --libs) -shared -o test.so -fPIC
php5 run.php

Array
(
    [0] => test 1
    [1] => test 2
    [2] => try vector
)
```

For reference the SWIG vector and string class are quite usable, given:

```
%module test

%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>

%template(StringVec) std::vector<std::string>;

%inline %{
std::vector<std::string> testSwig(const char *path)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("test 1");
    v.push_back("test 2");
    v.push_back("try vector");

    return v;
}
%}
```

The type `StringVec` is sane and can be used with no further work.

Comment: This example doesn't seem  to be working with PHP7. Has anyone got a working PHP7 example?

Comment: also have tested example with "template(StringVec)" and that doesn't work on both PHP7.2 and PHP5.6 unless it is missing something PHP prints out for me Resource id #5.

Comment: In order to make it happen with PHP 7 you can use "add_next_index_string($result, (char*) i->c_str() );" instead of ZVAL_STRINGL ... I've also added full answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

To add up on answer Flexo provieded.

In PHP7 zend API MAKE_STD_ZVAL() macro is removed (including some other things: https://wiki.php.net/phpng-upgrading )

In order to make this typemap working with PHP7 this is what I've did:

```
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::string> {
    array_init($result);
    $1_type::const_iterator i = $1.begin();
    $1_type::const_iterator e = $1.end();

    for(; i != e; ++i ) {
        add_next_index_string($result, (char*) i->c_str() );
    }
}
```

testSwig function from php prints just what's expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test 1
    [1] => test 2
    [2] => try vector
)
```